# Can not hook into Microsoft Store Application with SetWindowsHookEx and injected DLL

Tags: python, windows, winapi, hook, ctypes

I am trying to retrieve input messages. First i tried to do it globally, but the api says that Microsoft Store apps will not get injected. So i tried an application specific approach, which worked with a notepad app, but not with a Microsoft Whiteboard app, which makes me think its not really possible afterall.

Injected DLL:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker,"/section:Shared,rws")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK tHook;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    BOOL EnableMouseInPointer = TRUE;
    if (code == HC_ACTION) {
        LPMSG data = (LPMSG)lParam;
        if (data->message == WM_KEYDOWN || data->message == WM_POINTERUPDATE) {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hi", NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(tHook, code, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Python application code:

```
import ctypes
import os
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

user32 = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

user32.EnableMouseInPointer(True)

HC_ACTION = 0
WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
WH_GETMESSAGE = 3
WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4

def errcheck_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    return args

user32.SetWindowsHookExA.errcheck = errcheck_bool
user32.SetWindowsHookExA.restype = HHOOK
user32.SetWindowsHookExA.argtypes = (c_int,     # _In_ idHook
                                     HOOKPROC,  # _In_ lpfn
                                     HINSTANCE, # _In_ hMod
                                     DWORD)     # _In_ dwThreadId

user32.CallNextHookEx.restype = LRESULT
user32.CallNextHookEx.argtypes = (HHOOK,  # _In_opt_ hhk
                                  c_int,  # _In_     nCode
                                  WPARAM, # _In_     wParam
                                  LPARAM) # _In_     lParam

user32.GetMessageW.argtypes = (LPMSG, # _Out_    lpMsg
                               HWND,  # _In_opt_ hWnd
                               UINT,  # _In_     wMsgFilterMin
                               UINT)  # _In_     wMsgFilterMax

user32.TranslateMessage.argtypes = (LPMSG,)
user32.DispatchMessageW.argtypes = (LPMSG,)

GetModuleHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA
GetModuleHandle.restype = POINTER(c_void_p)

LoadLibrary = ctypes.windll.kernel32.LoadLibraryA
LoadLibrary.restype = HINSTANCE

GetProcAddress = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress
GetProcAddress.restype = HOOKPROC

user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId.restype = DWORD

def pointer_msg_loop():
    dll_name = 'Dll.dll'
    dll_abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.', dll_name))
    print(dll_abspath)
    lib = LoadLibrary('C:\\Users\\Braun\\Documents\\Git Kraken\\ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code\\MessagesDll\\x64\\Debug\\HOOKDLL.dll')
    handle = GetModuleHandle('C:\\Users\\Braun\\Documents\\Git Kraken\\ba-oliver-braun-logging-tool-code\\MessagesDll\\x64\\Debug\\HOOKDLL.dll')
    print(lib)
    print(handle)
    procedure = GetProcAddress(handle, "meconnect")
    print(procedure)
    if (procedure):
        print('correct value procedure')
        white = user32.FindWindowA(None, 'Microsoft Whiteboard')
        print(white)
        threadId = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(white, None)

        tHook = user32.SetWindowsHookExA(WH_GETMESSAGE, procedure, lib, threadId)
        time.sleep(30)
        user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(tHook)
        print(tHook)
        msg = MSG()
        while True:
            bRet = user32.GetMessageW(byref(msg), None, 0, 0)
            if not bRet:
                break
            if bRet == -1:
                raise WinError(get_last_error())
            user32.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
            user32.DispatchMessageW(byref(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    import datetime
    import threading
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    #print(ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(94))
    #tmouse = threading.Thread(target=mouse_msg_loop)
    #tkeyboard = threading.Thread(target=keyboard_msg_loop)
    ttouch = threading.Thread(target=pointer_msg_loop)
    #tmouse.start()
    #tkeyboard.start()
    ttouch.start()
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
       #     user32.PostThreadMessageW(tmouse.ident, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
            break
```

Comment: *Windows Store Apps* come with a totally new approach where *Win API* might no longer work.

Comment: Did you change the DACL permission on your windows store app folder first?  You can't do anything to the Windows Store App processes until you do that.  Right click on "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" and change the Owner to your account.  Then make sure you run as admin

Comment: @cri: That's wrong. First and foremost, a Windows Store App can really be anything from a classic desktop app to a UWP app. UWP applications run in a sandboxed app container, and access to some Windows API calls is limited through the runtime broker. But at the end of the day, UWP apps still ultimately call into the Windows API. And you can interoperate with UWP applications any way you like, given you have sufficient privileges. That bar was upped with the app container.

Comment: It seems to work if i specify a thread id, but messages i receive so far are underwhelming . I expected pointer messages, but its wm_paint messages ( talking about microsoft whiteboard.

Comment: When you hooked a notepad app, which message can be received?  WM_KEYDOWN or WM_POINTERUPDATE?

Comment: I apply the global hook to Microsoft whiteboard, but it seems that it has some special features, and can't get `WM_POINTERUPDATE` message, which needs further research.

Comment: If i use a key in the notepad lets say, i get the WM_KEY messages. If i use a pen i get POINTER messages. For Whiteboard i dont sadly

Comment: Do you test it on a device with a touch screen?

Comment: Yep i use a surface hub with pens and touch and it doesnt work. Other applications work fine tho

Comment: win32 hook application doesn't work for UWP since different security model, and what is your purpose of receiving messages from microsoft whiteboard?

Comment: I want to track user interaction and chose the whiteboard application as my example scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Windows Store app development** If dwThreadId is zero, then window hook DLLs are not loaded in-process for the Windows Store app
>   processes and the Windows Runtime broker process unless they are
>   installed by either UIAccess processes (accessibility tools). The
>   notification is delivered on the installer's thread for these hooks:
>
> - WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK
> - WH_JOURNALRECORD
> - WH_KEYBOARD
> - WH_KEYBOARD_LL
> - WH_MOUSE
> - WH_MOUSE_LL
>
> This behavior is similar to what happens when there is an architecture
>   mismatch between the hook DLL and the target application process, for
>   example, when the hook DLL is 32-bit and the application process
>   64-bit.

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) pointed out, In addition to the hooks mentioned above, other hooks cannot be applied to the Windows Store app.

Comment: Mhh so it is possible, but at the cost of not having global hook and having to use accessibility tools (not sure how to do that). Anyway thanks for the clarification!